# How to abstract the communication protocol used to communicate between different microservices?

Tags: rest, microservices, soap

I would like to implement a microservice which can support both `REST` and `SOAP`, and will use the protocol based on the client preference (or what the client is already using).

I have been thinking of a way to do that, I thought of header which will be set by the client to specify the protocol to be used, I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: Specify different endpoints for REST and SOAP calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both REST and SOAP commonly use HTTP as their transport medium, but that is where the commonality between them ends.

As REST and SOAP don't even agree on *how* HTTP is used, the easiest way to support both in a single service is to provide different routes/endpoints for REST communication and different routes/endpoints for SOAP communication.

Just consider it two independent API's that both call into the same library for doing the actual work.